# Get the first post term

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

How do I get only the first term of a custom post type.
I can get all - no problem. This what I am using to grab all of them

```
<?php foreach ($terms as $term) {echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'sitecat').'">'.$term->name.'</a>,';} ?> >> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title('', ''); ?></a></h2></span>
```

Would appreciate an answer using my code but any help is most welcomed

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'first' taxonomy... but,

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'mytaxonomy' );
```

returns an array of taxonomy term objects, so

```
$term = array_pop($terms);
```

Would give you the first term in the array. And then:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'mytaxonomy').'">'.$term->name.'</a>,'
```

*(You may want to include some if statements, in case an empty array or error is returned (see [`is_wp_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error))*

Comment: ok.. the error was on my side - not your answer ;) thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 7):

As of PHP 5.4, you can directly [dereference](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) an array, so to get the first term, you can simply do.

```
$first_term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'TAXONOMY_NAME' )[0];
var_dump( $first_term );
```

If you need a specific property (*say the term name*) of the first term, you can do the following

```
$first_term_name = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'TAXONOMY_NAME' )[0]->name;
var_dump( $first_term_name );
```

### EDIT

Just a note, this does have its draw backs because you will get a `WP_Error` object if the taxonomy is invalid. Also, if the returned array is empty, you will also get an undefined array key warning, so use this with with care.

Comment: How would i get all term id's foreach post for use on the home age archive @pieter-goosen

Answer (score 2):

how about directly access the key of object?

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sitecat' );
$first_term = $terms[0];
```

so you can access the object.

```
echo $first_term->name;
```

Comment: Its best to check this index exists but this work ;)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize all the previous answers here is the helper gist I use. Does all the necessary checks and accepts same arguments as the **get_the_terms()** function.

```
function getTheFirstTerm($post, $taxonomy) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

    if (!empty($terms)  && !is_wp_error( $terms )) {
        //this line effectively returns the first available term object if there is one.
        return $terms[0];
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Further note.**
This function for simplicity that's needed in most of my cases just returns the term object or false. You can still return WP_Error if up the flow you need check for it i.e.

```
if (!empty($terms)) {
   if(!is_wp_error( $terms )) {
       //this line effectively returns the first available term object if there is one.
       return $terms[0];
   } else {
       return $terms; //This returns the WP_Error object
   }       
}
```

Moreover you can sort the terms before returning the first i.e. so you get first term object by term_id, slug, name, menu order and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer j.w. ;)

Comment: You may point out in your code that which part give the first term so that other user may refer to it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. It brings only the first category as text, no anchor.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'your_custom_taxonomy' ); 
foreach( $terms as $term ) { 
    print $term->name;
    break;
    unset($term);
}
```

Comment: What "worked for you"? Sidenote: The `break;` will really stop your statement, the `unset` will never be triggered and only the 1st item will be processed.

Comment: `unset( $term );` should be **after** your `foreach` loop, and not **inside** it :-)

Comment: This won't work if the returned terms are WP_Error.