# Get only the first term by taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Maybe it's a stupid question but I can't find the answer.

I have a custom taxonomy (directores) and each director is a term. Some times a film has more than one director. I need to print only the first director no all directors from one film.

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the first Category / Term only in single-custom-post.php](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45083/get-the-first-category-term-only-in-single-custom-post-php)

Answer (score 8):

how about use `get_the_terms()` function?

please try this code

```
$directores = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'directores' ); 
$director = $directores[0];

// print object from first director
print_r($director);

// or get the director name
echo $director->name;
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally I read the Wordpress doc [Reference/get terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

```
$args = array('number' => '1',);
$terms = get_terms('director', $args );
foreach( $terms as $term ){
  echo  $term->name ;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use this code for access first texonomy from custom post type in wordpress

how about use get_the_terms() function?

please try this code

$works = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'work' ); 
$director = $works[0];

// print object from first director
print_r($director);

// or get the director name
echo $director->name;

Comment: Please clean up your code. There's the WYSIWYG editor for formatting.